# Density of measurable sets in $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb {R} $. We can classify the points in $\mathbb{R}$ as 3 disjoint subsets: density 0 points $A_1$, density 1 points $A_2$, otherwise $A_3$. By the Lebesgue density theorem, $A_3$ is measure zero.

Question: Can I prove $m(A)=m(A_2)=m(cl(A_2))$? Or does some equality fail? Here $m$ is the usual Lebesgue measure and the closure is taken in the usual topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. See [this construction](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26000/75670). Take $A = U$. Then $A$ is open, so $A = A_2$ and $cl(A_2) = cl(A)$. But $cl(A) \setminus A$ contains a fat Cantor set of positive measure.

Hence, $m(A) = m(A_2)$ (that's the Lebesgue density theorem) but in general $m(A) \leq m(cl(A_2))$.

Comment: In your construction, is it true that the density at the boundary is not $1$?

Comment: @John Ma: in this example, the density of $A$ at the boundary is not $1$ for almost every point of the boundary. It is at least $1/2$ at least at the endpoints of the intervals which make up $A$, though.